# How to call a variable as a path from another script?

Tags: linux, bash

Example

```
Var = '/etc/sysconfig/..'
export Var
bash script1.sh
```

in another script1

```
cat $Var
```

This is my Problem: The variable does not call the file in this path

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
Var='/etc/sysconfig/..'
bash script1.sh "$Var"
```

Then in `script1.sh`:

```
Var=$1
cat "$Var"
```

The quotes around `"$Var"` are required to support paths containing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable assignment is wrong, it should be:

```
Var='/etc/sysconfig/..'
```

No spaces around `=`.

If you want to send in a environment variable for one script only then you can use:

```
Var='/etc/sysconfig/..' ./my_script.sh
```

And inside `my_script.sh`:

```
printf "%s\n" "$Var"
# Will print /etc/sysconfig/..
```

If you want to send arguments to `my_script.sh` do what [@JohnZwinck suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36885861/887539). What I suggested is only to change environment variable and shouldn't be abused to send/receive regular variables to a command.

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to to more thing

script 1

```
#!/bin/bash
a="/home/example"  ### you can do with export command also export a="/home/example"
```

sctipt2 ## make effective

```
. script1; 
cd $a
```